# Skype COM in VB6: Event for "authorization requested"?

Tags: api, skype

I am using the Skype COM object ("SKYPE4COMLib.Skype") in VB6.

Is there a way to get an event when Skype displays the message "FILENAME wants to connect to Skype. Do you want to allow this?" in the Skype window?

I want to show a messagebox in my app that tells the user that he has to click "Allow" in the Skype window, because this message in the Skype window is so easy to overlook.

But I do not want to bug the user all the time with this messagebox. 
Perhaps the user has already confirmed this question in Skype before, and this authorization question is not shown anymore.

That is why I would like to get an event that tells me that this question is actually show in the Skype Window.

Or did anybody find any other smart solution for this problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB6, there is this "Status" event. It contains information that tells one about the authorization status. Seems quite a bit buggy to me, but it is a starting point anyway.